# xamarin forms template default error "The type 'Color' does not support direct content"

Tags: c#, templates, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile-application

I had downloaded Visual studio 2019 then I try to create new Mobile APP (Xamarin.forms) > Master detail page. After create, I just try to build it, but it shows this error.

[image: Error Screenshot]

I wondering why. Am I missing something or need to install some other component? This couldn't be right.
Anyone having this issue before? How to resolve this?

Comment: go to line 13-15 and look how you use Color.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade your **`visual studio 2019`** to the latest version.
It helps for me.